# Will I be able to install Windows 10 using just my OEM serial number

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have a laptop that was originally on Windows 7 and still has the OEM windows sticker with serial number on the bottom. I've now reformatted completely removing windows and have installed Ubuntu instead.

Will I be able to install the free Windows 10 upgrade anyhow using my OEM windows serial number?

Comment: Upgrade is an upgrade, you can't upgrade nothing to Windows 10.

Comment: You will need to install Windows 7 first, if you want the free upgrade, to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install windows 7 on the device and run "Get Windows 10 (GWX)" and reserve your copy

worked for me, i fished out a ancient 7 install media with key