# reinstall windows 10 after windows7-to-10-upgrade - how to do it

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

While reading superuser's suggestions for my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1706575/reinstall-windows-10-after-windows7-to-10-upgrade-what-serial-number-to-use), I noticed there are 2 ways of reinstalling win10 after win7-to-10-upgrade

1. [some superusers' users](https://superuser.com/questions/947703/windows-10-upgrade-after-formatting) suggest to just install win10, directly and don't worry about it (win7 was phased to win10);
2. [other superusers' users](https://superuser.com/questions/943331/will-i-be-able-to-install-windows-10-using-just-my-oem-serial-number) suggest to reinstall win7 and re-update;

Which path should I take if I have slow/virused/crappy software filled win7, which I need to replace with win10? 1 or 2?

Thanks
R

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reinstall windows 10 after windows7-to-10-upgrade - what serial number to use](https://superuser.com/questions/1706575/reinstall-windows-10-after-windows7-to-10-upgrade-what-serial-number-to-use)

Comment: Windows 10 uses a digital entitlement, if a machine has had Windows 10, then it will automatically activate[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1256581/can-i-reinstall-windows-without-reactivating-it/1256584#1256584)  There is absolutely no reason to provide a license key unless you are dealing with a fresh installation and you are installing a Retail copy of Windows 10[.](https://superuser.com/questions/947232).  The activation process of Windows 10 is well documented in several questions that have accurate answers.  I am treating this as a duplicate of the proposed duplicate.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to provide a license key .... That is what I said

Comment: So it should be closed as a duplicate.  The question about how Windows 10 digital entitlement works has been asked and answered in the past.

Comment: You always know more than I do so I deleted both answers. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

After updating Windows 7 to Windows 10 your current Windows 7 Key is upgraded to a Windows 10 key. So you can use it to activate your Windows 10 Installation.

For the installation itself, you can either do a clean reinstall from a DVD or USB-Stick with the iso file or you go to the Windows 10 Settings > Update & Security > Recovery and click on "Get started" of "Reset this PC". Then it will guide you through the steps to reinstall Windows 10. I still prefer the clean reinstall from an ISO file.

I've done it multiple times and it shouldn't be an issue at all for you. ;)